# Failure in MoveIt! move_group on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 ROS Kinetic on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group, fcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to implement and build my manipulator packages on the Raspberry Pi 3, once I have already successfully installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04, ROS Kinetic and MoveIt!, but there are some problems related with the move_group node when I launch my .launch file, although everything worked fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop .

This is what happens when I launch it on the Raspberry Pi 3:

```
[ INFO] [1500982430.452887547]: Loading robot model 'manipulator'...
...
[move_group-4] process has died [pid 2757, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --debug __name:=move_group __log:=/home/david/.ros/log/1f22c09e-712d-11e7-8611-7989bb2a9d91/move_group-4.log].
log file: /home/david/.ros/log/1f22c09e-712d-11e7-8611-7989bb2a9d91/move_group-4*.log
```

I suppose that the problem must be related with the FCL collision libraries of MoveIt! and how they work on Raspberry Pi 3, since if I remove all the visual and collision elements of my URDF file everything works well, but then obviously collisions could not be detected. Anyway, I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem yet, anyone can help me?

Thanks

UPDATE:

This is what I get running the launch file with debug=true

```
Reading symbols from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
/home/david/1566_embedded_man/embedded_man/rosws/src/manipulator_moveit_config_V3/launch/gdb_settings.gdb: No such file or directory.
Starting program: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --debug __name:=move_group __log:=/home/david/.ros/log/7e9d1980-7131-11e7-8611-7989bb2a9d91/move_group-4.log
enter code here
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76fd9dde in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
(gdb)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267898/failure-in-moveit!-move_group-on-ubuntu-mate-16.04-ros-kinetic-on-raspberry-pi-3/) by [davideuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/31422/davideuse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-03**:\

> no debugging symbols found

as you can see, `gdb` doesn't have any symbols, so it can't give you a proper backtrace.

you can try to see what the output is when you enter `bt` and then press the `<enter>` key, but I doubt it will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

< assumption>Is the fcl package for the raspberry pi *still* broken?< /assumption>

This segfault gets reported up over and over again for the last couple of months (at least) and you should be able to find github issues, mails to moveit-users and/or rosanswers issues on this (assuming it's the same issue)...

The last thing I heard about this were some speculations on broken compiler flags used to build the package.

Maybe you can get it to work by compiling FCL from source?
http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/dependencies/

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-02**:
Seeing as this is an ARM platform, it could also be the suspect mesh loading that makes things crash on platforms != x86-64.

@davideuse: `-11` is a `SEGFAULT`. It would really help if you could post a backtrace.

**Comment by [davideuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/31422/davideuse/) on 2017-08-03**:
@gvdhoorn: I am using binary .stl files in the mesh, do you think that this could be the problem?
I have updated the issue with a backtrace running the launch file with debug=true as you suggested

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-03**:
That is not a backtrace. You'll need to enter `bt` into `gdb`'s prompt and execute that.

**Comment by [davideuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/31422/davideuse/) on 2017-08-03**:
Yes but it doesn't work either, this is what I get then:

```
#0 0x76fd9dde in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#1 0x76fd9dde in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-03**:
Then you'll have to probably build MoveIt from source if you want to get a proper backtrace. But it could be that stack smashing makes this impossible anyway, regardless of whether the symbols are present.

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-10-24**:
Bumping this, I'm experiencing the same issue. Installing FCL from source didn't fix anything so I'm currently trying to install moveit from source to test that. Will post back with any results.

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-10-26**:
Installed from source and came across the same issue. I've bumped an existing issue on the moveit github page with some output from gdb. - https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/564